# Programming practice char * pointer to const or array to const

Tags: c++, constants

I know that following is bad programming practice

```
char * p1 = "myBad"  ;
```

The above is bad as const "myBad" memory is getting pointed by non Const pointer . Compilers allow p1 as to support backward compatibility with C

IS the following a bad practice too ?

```
char p2[]="myBadORGood";
```

Whats the difference betweeen p1 and p2 . DOes compiler make a non-const copy for p2 ?  I think i read somewhere that p2 is fine  but not sure  ..

Comment: The second is totally fine. You get an array with modifiable contents. The string literal is copied into the array on initialisation.

Comment: Note that it is no longer valid C++.

Comment: @chris .. you meant p2 is no longer valid ? if yes whats the best way

Comment: @MAG, `p1`, actually. C++11 disallowed `char *` pointing to string literals, and I'm very glad for it, as almost all cases of that were bugs.

Answer (score 3):

`p2` is initialized by the string literal, i.e. it is a *copy* of the string literal, so `p2` being non-`const` is fine:

```
char p2[]="myGood";
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is not only bad practice but *deprecated* in C++ (C++03; according to chris' comment this is even *illegal* now in *C++11*).

The second is totally fine, the string literal is only used as a (read-only) "model" to initialize a new, independent array. Thus, the short

```
char arr[] = "abc";
```

is equivalent to the longer

```
char arr[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
```

and can even be written like this:

```
char arr[4];
arr[0] = 'a';
arr[1] = 'b';
arr[2] = 'c';
arr[3] = '\0';
```

(but don't write code like that! ^^)